# Why does setting line-height for one of two inline-block sibling divs effect both divs?

Tags: html, css

I have the following:

```
<div>
    <div style="display:inline-block; ">div_1</div>
    <div style="display:inline-block; line-height:20px;">div_2</div>
</div>
```

Why does having a line-height property set for the second div also effects the first div?  And how to correct for this i only need the second div to be effected by line-height because I need to specify a different `line-height` for the first div.  *Thanks in advance.*

```js
document.getElementById('go').onclick = function(e) {
  document.getElementById('div_2').style.lineHeight = '30px';
};
```

```html
<button id="go">Go</button>
<div>
  <div style="display:inline-block;" id="div_1">div_1</div>
  <div style="display:inline-block; line-height:24px;" id="div_2">div_2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) demonstration of your problem. It makes it *so much* easier to answer your question.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

With the test case, it's now crystal clear.

Add `vertical-align: top` to the first div:

```
<div style="display:inline-block; line-height:24px; vertical-align: top" id="div_1">div_1</div>
```

Fixed version: http://jsfiddle.net/my6Su/5/

Read this to understand the relationship between `display: inline-block` and `vertical-align`:
http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/

Also useful, for a visual demonstration:
http://www.brunildo.org/test/inline-block.html

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, the effect of [line-height](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-line-height) is only on inline elements. When [line-height is applied to block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/line-height), inline-block or any other type of element that is not inline, the [effects are on the inline descendant](https://webplatform.github.io/docs/css/properties/line-height/) elements only.

Secondly, in a line-box (an abstract box enclosing inline elements in a line), all the inline elements are aligned along the baseline. When you change the line-height for the second div, it adds half-leading at the top (and bottom) of that inline-element. And top half-leading pushes the baseline lower, which in turn moves the first div lower.

I am not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve, but, I would recommend either using the vertical-align property or just use position relative.

Comment: I only halfway understand what you're describing but you obviously have a thorough understanding of how CSS layout works; thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
    <div style="display:inline-block; line-height:10px;">div_1</div>
    <div style="display:inline-block; line-height:20px;">div_2</div>
</div>
```

try this. this will work.

Comment: explain how this will work rather only a snippet. avoid inline style. add it as a class. if possible add this working demo will help asker !