# How do I align div elements where some have text and some don't?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have a series of inline-block div elements inside a parent block div element all sit at the same height. Some of the divs have text in them and others do not. The text in the divs needs to be vertically centered but not horizontally. I used line-height to center the text, but the div with no text does not align with the others. Here is my code:

```
<div class='line'>    
    <div class='someText'>text 1</div>    
    <div class='someText'>text 2</div>    
    <div class='noText'></div>    
    <div class='someText'>text 3</div>    
    <div class='someText'>text 4</div>
</div>


.line{
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    max-height: 50px;
}

.someText{
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 50px;
    background-color: RED;
    padding: 10px;
}

.noText {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    width:50px;
    background-color: BLUE;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Could anyone explain to me why this is happening and/or give a possible solution? I would like to avoid using tables if possible.

Thanks!

Also here is a jsfiddle showing the problem. https://jsfiddle.net/n1LbcLr1/

Comment: Adding `vertical-align: top;` to both of your ~text div classes might help. Please see if it helps: https://jsfiddle.net/n1LbcLr1/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer here: [Why does setting line-height for one of two inline-block sibling divs effect both divs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373400/why-does-setting-line-height-for-one-of-two-inline-block-sibling-divs-effect-bot)

You can simply add `vertical-align: top;` to the divs with text.

Blue div positioned itself at the text baseline. If you change vertical-align to top it will position itself correctly.